# Add JTextField to Game Menu (graphics2d)

Tags: java, jtextfield, graphics2d

I'm developing a multiplayer game, and at the menu, I need to add a field, where the player can type the host-ip.

I'm making the menu with Graphics2D, and I'm updating it in a loop:

```
JFrame screenFrame = screen.getFullScreenWindow();
while (menuIsRunning) {        
    Graphics2D g = screen.getGraphics();
    renderer.drawMenu(g, screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight(), menuObjects);
    screenFrame.getLayeredPane().paintComponents(g);
    g.dispose();
    screen.update();
}
```

And there I want to add a JTextField too, like this:

```
Container contentPane = screenFrame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(null);
JTextField text = new JTextField("Enter text here", 28);
contentPane.add(text);
text.setBounds(10,10,20,20);
screenFrame.validate();
```

And it appears on the screen, but when I'm typing in it, after a few sec, it just freezes or something (no error message). I can't type anymore, and all the other keyActions don't work either (like escape: exit the game)

I tried to see something with focusListener:

```
text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("focus gained");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("focus lost");
        }
    });
```

It says when the focus gained, but when textfield freezes it doesn't say anything about focus lost.
If I just click in the textfield, I can still use other functions, but when I begint to type it will freeze.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Are you able to post a more complete example of your code as opposed to just the above sections?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know exactly what you want me to post. The code is pretty large now.
The main problem: I'm rendering a menu, and I want to add a swing object. And that object doesn't work like it should be. 
One moment, I'll add more code, just need to edit a little bit to be more understandable.

Comment: A component is more the it's graphics.  It needs to be attached to an appropriate displayed component so that it respond to events.  It is also tied to the Event Dispatching Thread so that it can post updates to the event queue.  What you are trying to achieve may not be possible the way you are trying to achieve it...

Comment: I'm trying to do a simple menu. I do infinite loop, cause I'm drawing all the components of the menu. 
  Example: Instead of JButton, I use an image, and when I click on the image the action will be executed. (For this, I store the image position, width and height).
Maybe I should try the menu just only with swing. I thought it won't be a big problem to mix the 2 things.